# Swift: How to redirect user to Add Contact screen with contact number

Tags: xcode, swift3, addressbook

I have a mobile number on my view controller and using that mobile number I want to redirect the user to the Add Contact screen (Address Book).

Please note that I don't want to fill other fields (name, image and all) in background, just redirect the user to add a contact screen with a contact number where they can edit and save it accordingly.

Note: the problem is that I just started Swift and I'm actually from an Android background and I don't have an idea if there is any actions with intents just like this in Swift too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the following

```
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
```

Add CNContactViewControllerDelegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CNContactViewControllerDelegate
```

And the following code

```
let newContact = CNMutableContact()
newContact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: "home", value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: "123456")))
let contactVC = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: newContact)
contactVC.contactStore = CNContactStore()
contactVC.delegate = self
contactVC.allowsActions = false
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactVC) //For presenting the vc you have to make it navigation controller otherwise it will not work, if you already have navigatiation controllerjust push it you dont have to make it a navigation controller
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: how to add a back button after presenting the screen,i mean dismissing screen (pop).

Comment: func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactVC, animated: true)